# php function to decode arabic text in url to percent encoding like firefox

Tags: php

i have this url

```
http://al-mashhad.com/News/النيابة-تستمع-لأقوال-خالد-يوسف-في-بلاغه-ضد-أبو-إسم/141274.aspx
```

firefox change it to

```
http://al-mashhad.com/News/%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%86%D9%8A%D8%A7%D8%A8%D8%A9-%D8%AA%D8%B3%D8%AA%D9%85%D8%B9-%D9%84%D8%A3%D9%82%D9%88%D8%A7%D9%84-%D8%AE%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AF-%D9%8A%D9%88%D8%B3%D9%81-%D9%81%D9%8A-%D8%A8%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%BA%D9%87-%D8%B6%D8%AF-%D8%A3%D8%A8%D9%88-%D8%A5%D8%B3%D9%85/141274.aspx
```

i want php function to do that task

i tryied [urencode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php), but its do that

```
http%3A%2F%2Fal-mashhad.com%2FNews%2F%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%86%D9%8A%D8%A7%D8%A8%D8%A9-%D8%AA%D8%B3%D8%AA%D9%85%D8%B9-%D9%84%D8%A3%D9%82%D9%88%D8%A7%D9%84-%D8%AE%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AF-%D9%8A%D9%88%D8%B3%D9%81-%D9%81%D9%8A-%D8%A8%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%BA%D9%87-%D8%B6%D8%AF-%D8%A3%D8%A8%D9%88-%D8%A5%D8%B3%D9%85%2F141274.aspxstring(296) "http://al-mashhad.com%2FNews%2F%D8%A7%D9%84%D9%86%D9%8A%D8%A7%D8%A8%D8%A9-%D8%AA%D8%B3%D8%AA%D9%85%D8%B9-%D9%84%D8%A3%D9%82%D9%88%D8%A7%D9%84-%D8%AE%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%AF-%D9%8A%D9%88%D8%B3%D9_-%D9_%D9%8A-%D8%A8%D9%84%D8%A7%D8%BA%D9%87-%D8%B6%D8%AF-%D8%A3%D8%A8%D9%88-%D8%A5%D8%B3%D9%85%2F141274.aspx"
```

and i want it change the arabic text only, just like mozilla firefox

because its corrupt http:// and /

Comment: will return the first url without any thing else

Comment: I would post the answer like @jap1968.

Answer (score 2):

You could split the full URI just taking into account the slash character (/) and encode only the final fragment.

You could also access the server information. In PHP you can access the variable $_SERVER['SCRIPT_NAME'] to recover the part of the URI that you want to encode. I do not know about how that is made in ASP.

Comment: this is not the url of the site .. its just varibale so i cant use $_SERVER